# difference between visiting a file through emacs or with emacsclient?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

The reason why I ask is for most thing they appear similar, except when using Thunderbird External Editor Extension (with editor designated as `emacsclient -c`). Closing the frame created with this emacsclient instance with `C-x C-c` (`C-x #` does not work sometimes?) will also kill the buffer associated with this frame (not the usual emacsclient behavior).

And, in general, `C-x C-c` will just close the frame unless another buffer is visited in that frame -- after this, `C-x C-c` will try to close all of emacs. How do I try to understand this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

From Emacs, you can get help for any key by pressing C-h k and then entering the key combination that you want to know about. Pressing C-h k C-x # returns this:

> C-x # runs the command server-edit, which is an interactive compiled
>   Lisp function in `server.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x #.
>
> (server-edit &optional ARG)
>
> Switch to next server editing buffer; say "Done" for current buffer.
>   If a server buffer is current, it is marked "done" and optionally
>   saved. The buffer is also killed if it did not exist before the
>   clients asked for it. When all of a client's buffers are marked as
>   "done", the client is notified.
>
> Temporary files such as MH  files are always saved and backed
>   up, no questions asked.  (The variable 'make-backup-files', if nil,
>   still inhibits a backup; you can set it locally in a particular buffer
>   to prevent a backup for it.)  The variable 'server-temp-file-regexp'
>   controls which filenames are considered temporary.
>
> If invoked with a prefix argument, or if there is no server process
>   running, starts server process and that is all.  Invoked by C-x #. C-x #
>   runs the command server-edit, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
>   function in 'server.el'.

Similarly for C-x C-c

> C-x C-c runs the command save-buffers-kill-terminal, which is an
>   interactive compiled Lisp function in `files.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-x C-c,   .
>
> (save-buffers-kill-terminal &optional ARG)
>
> Offer to save each buffer, then kill the current connection. If the
>   current frame has no client, kill Emacs itself.
>
> With prefix ARG, silently save all file-visiting buffers, then kill.
>
> If emacsclient was started with a list of filenames to edit, then only
>   these files will be asked to be saved.